# nginx - rewrite domain.com:port to sub.domain.com

Tags: proxy, nginx, subdomain, url-rewriting

How can i rewrite a domain with a port to a subdomain?

e.q.: `domain.com:3000` to `sub.domain.com` ?

thanks for your help! :)

greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you actually want to redirect (301 or 302) your web traffic

You create a `server {}` section listening on port 3000 and you just redirect it to another `server {}` section that is listening on port 80. In each `server {}` section set the `listen` property appropriately.
I guess you are trying to handle the redirection within à single `server` section and according to [this page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) the `listen` directive applies to a `server` context

### If you want to use nginx as a proxy

Then what you are looking for is the proxy_pass directive. Here is a sample configuration extracted from an config I have to use nginx as a proxy for my rails app (thin). Basically my app runs locally (but it would also work on a remote host) on port 3200 and the relevant nginx config part looks as follow:

```
  upstream my-app-cluster
  {
      server localhost:3200;
  }  
  server
  {
    listen       80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
  
    root /root/to/public/folder;
    
    access_log  /my/app/log/folder/myapp.log;
    
    location / {
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
  
      if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
      }
      if (-f $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
      }
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://my-app-cluster;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's a ruby on rail (https://github.com/gitlabhq) application that is listening on port 3000
`Restarting nginx: nginxnginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:3000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()`

My Server Sections
http://pastebin.com/6yacUyDV
`

Comment: Updated my answer. What you are having here is normal. your rails app listens port 3000, and this process is absolutely independent from nginx. If you se nginx to also run on port 3000 you get the message above. There can be only 1 process at a time listening on a given port. If you stop your rails app, then run nginx, then launch your rails app, then rails will tell you that the address is already in use :)

Comment: thanks!!
this was my first question on stackoverflow and it's already answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Passenger in nginx to delivery the Ruby app - that's the method we are currently using.

http://www.modrails.com/