# nginx access subdomain.domain.com as domain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, dns, http-redirect

I am new to `nginx` system and previously, I managed to access `subdomain.domain.com:3000` through `subdomain.domain.com`(without port no.) through the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478149/1120530).

I am finding difficulty in achieving following:

I want to access my Rails server running in `subdomain.domain.com` through `domain.com`. i.e
 when someone hit url `domain.com` in browser then it should act as `subdomain.domain.com` but url should not change it browser.

Could anyone help me how can I achieve it?

I have commented out default settings in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and created my
own setting in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myblog` as:

```
upstream my-app-cluster
{
    server blog.budhram.com:3000;
}
server
{
    listen       80;
    server_name budhram.com;
    # above not working but if used blog.budhram.com then working but not expected

    # rails app public folder path
    root /home/ubuntu/myblog/public;

    # rails app log file path
    access_log  /home/ubuntu/myblog/log/development.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
            rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
        }
        if (-f $request_filename.html) {
            rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           proxy_pass http://my-app-cluster;
           break;
        }
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a little more clarity on the question and the `nginx.conf` file needs to added.

Comment: @RobertChristopher Updated with my nginx config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up desired host for proxy, url should not change in browser, but this can change hostname-based links on proxied site:

```
proxy_set_header Host subdomain.domain.com;
```